# calculate length and perimeter of triangle from points

Tags: c

y coordinates from user as double variable  and calculating them if points forms a triangle but i cant get correct result.
I think there is a problem about using double variables for example if i put integer variable to x1 , y1 it does not calculate mAB

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    double x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3;

    printf("Enter x , y coordinates of first vertice!\n");

    scanf("%lf",&x1);
    scanf("%lf",&y1);
/*
    if(isInteger(x1)==0)
    {
        printf("\ndouble");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nint");
    }
    */
    /*********************************************/
    printf("Enter x , y coordinates of second vertice!\n");

    scanf("%lf",&x2);
    scanf("%lf",&y2);
    /*********************************************/
    printf("Enter x , y coordinates of third vertice!\n");

    scanf("%lf",&x3);
    scanf("%lf",&y3);
    /*********************************************/
    /*********************************************/

    double mAB = (fabs(x1-x2) / fabs(y1-y2));
    double mAC = (fabs(x1-x3) / fabs(y1-y3));

    printf("\n mAB %lf", mAB);
    printf("\n mAC %lf", mAC);

    if(mAB == mAC)
    {
        printf("These points does not forms a triangle!!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        /*
        * 1-2 AB
        * 1-3 AC
        * 2-3 BC
        */
        double distancexAB = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1);
        double distanceyAB = (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1);
        double distanceAB = csqrt(fabs(distancexAB - distanceyAB));
        /*********************************************/
        double distancexAC = (x3 - x1) * (x3 - x1);
        double distanceyAC = (y3 - y1) * (y3 - y1);
        double distanceAC = csqrt(fabs(distancexAC - distanceyAC));
        /*********************************************/
        double distancexBC = (x2 - x3) * (x2 - x3);
        double distanceyBC = (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3);
        double distanceBC = csqrt(fabs(distancexBC - distanceyBC));
        /*********************************************/
        printf("\n AB %lf", distanceAB);
        printf("\n AC %lf", distanceAC);
        printf("\n BC %lf", distanceBC);

        double perimeter = distanceAB+distanceAC+distanceBC;
        printf("\n Perimeter: %lf", perimeter);

    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Test results:

```
Enter x , y coordinates of first vertice!
1 1
Enter x , y coordinates of second vertice!
2 2
Enter x , y coordinates of third vertice!
3 3

 mAB 1.000000
 mAC 1.000000These points does not forms a triangle!!!!
```

Second test

```
Enter x , y coordinates of first vertice!
3.4 5.6
Enter x , y coordinates of second vertice!
1.2 3.4
Enter x , y coordinates of third vertice!
1.8 9.8

 mAB 1.000000
 mAC 0.380952
 AB 0.000000
 AC 3.883298
 BC 6.371813
 Perimeter: 10.255111
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? What value do you enter as input? Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Take the [tour] make a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "does not calculate"? Does it crash or output an incorrect value? Which one? Please provide us with sample input and output.

Comment: sorry forget put test results

Comment: The use of `fabs()` in `double mAB = (fabs(x1-x2) / fabs(y1-y2));
    double mAC = (fabs(x1-x3) / fabs(y1-y3));` is incorrect to detect a degenerate triangle.

Comment: double mAB = (abs(x1-x2) / abs(y1-y2));
there is a problem at here if i enter integer calculates 1 as i show show on second example

Comment: Why are you using `csqrt()` when everything should be real? In the first case, the points (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) do not form a triangle--that's correct, they fall in a straight line. But your distance calculations are off-the perimeter of the second triangle should be 14.49. Distance is the sqrt of the sum of squares, and you're subtracting. Don't need `fabs()` either.

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the distance between points by adding the sum of squares, not subtracting them.   `fabs()` not needed.  `sqrt()` is sufficient.  [@Alexander Daum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505266/2410359).
   Even better, use `hypot()`.

> The `hypot` functions compute the square root of the sum of the squares of `x` and `y`, without undue overflow or underflow. C11 §7.12.7.3 2

```
    double distancexAB = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1);
    double distanceyAB = (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1);
    // double distanceAB = csqrt(fabs(distancexAB - distanceyAB));
    double distanceAB = sqrt(distancexAB + distanceyAB);

    // or even more simple
    double distanceAB = hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

2. OP uses weak code to detect if slopes are parallel.  2 problems:
   `fabs()` loses the sign of the slope.
   OP's method is subject to divide by 0.0.

   ```
   // Alternative code:
   double delta_x12 = x1 - x2;
   double delta_y12 = y1 - y2;
   double delta_x13 = x1 - x3;
   double delta_y13 = y1 - y3;
   if (delta_x12*delta_y13 == delta_y12*delta_x13) {
     printf("These points do not form a triangle.");
   }
   ```

---

If OP wants to calculate the area, code could use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) and use that to determine if  "points do not form a triangle".

```
    double a = hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
    double b = hypot(x2 - x3, y2 - y3);
    double c = hypot(x2 - x1, y3 - y1);
    double perimeter = a + b + c;
    double s /* semi-perimeter */ = perimeter/2;
    double area2 = s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c);

    // due to small inaccuracies, area2 may be negative.
    double area = area2 > 0.0 ? sqrt(area2) : 0.0;

    if (area == 0) {
      printf("These points do not form a triangle.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where calculating distances, you have to write:

```
double distanceAB = sqrt(distancexAB + distanceyAB);
```

instead of

```
double distanceAB = csqrt(fabs(distancexAB - distanceyAB));
```

Because the distance is the hypothenuse and use sqrt instead of csqrt, because csqrt is intended for complex variables.
You don't need fabs, because `distancexAB` and `distanceyAB` are squares and so they cannot be negative, and the sum of two positive numbers will be positive as long as no overflow occurs.

Comment: Don't need fabs() either because `distancexAB` and `distanceyAB` are guaranteed to be non-negative.

Comment: Thanks, I've overlooked that